# GCP METADATA OSCONFIG:TRUE casues yum check-update to fail repo not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, metadata

With the new OS Patching feature in GCP on Debian 9 Stretch>>

Having added the settings for the project metadata enable-osconfig to true and enable-guest-attributes to true, GCP Logging is showing the following error log:-

```
Error Applying yum changes, attempt 1, retrying in 1s: error running yum with args ["check-update" "--assumeyes"]: exit status 1, stdout: There are no enabled repos. Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have. You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>

having Run "yum repolist all" the response is repolist: 0
it appears that yum cannot find the repo that OSCONFIG metadata has attempted to add
Log entry: Writing repo file /etc/yum.repos.d/google_osconfig_managed.repo with updated contents
```

How do I now solve the error and get yum-config-manager to reference and install this repo that apparently exists (as above)?

I have tried variations of :

```
yum -config-manager --enable /etc/yum.repos.d/google_osconfig_managed.repo
```

but to no avail oddly the reponse is:

```
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///home/accounts/onfig-manager
```

Any ideas? even the URL to the REPO might help?!

*p.s. I'll need the exact syntax as I'm not familiar really with BASH*

Answer (score 0):

I note you are mixing Operating Systems; For Debian 9 Stretch, firs of all install the agent by running this commands [0], then you will need to add the debian repository [1], then if you are not uising "Google-provided image" you will need to import the Google Cloud public key [2]. Finally, verify the agent is running in your instance [3]:

[0]

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt -y install google-osconfig-agent`

[1]

`sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt \ google-compute-engine-stretch-stable main'> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-compute-engine.list"`

[2]

`curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | \ sudo apt-key add -`

[3]

`systemctl status google-osconfig-agent`

Note: yum is used for CentOS/RedHat OS. Yoy can see detailed information and "how to" guides about this in [GCP official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#debian)

Comment: Thank you very much Jujosiga, I've run those two commands, not really knowing if I needed to run 2. There was no feedback from Debian after running each command, i thought that I might see that the Repo had been added after running 1. Is there a debian 9 command to check the success of the commands? Or is it a case of adding the metadata again and seeing if it errors now? I don't actually know if I am using a google provided image. How would I check that? I am running something called 3CX PBX Express, which essentially installed a PBX and setup the VM, albeit I had to pick the type of VM.

Comment: Secondly, the YUM error is simply being generated and showing in the Log

I am not aware of setting up yum, other than by accident, in Debian. So do i need to disable/uninstall it? and if so how do I do that? sudo apt-get remove yum?

Comment: P.S I did it anyway (uninstalled yum) with my fingers crossed and so far no errors, so I think that was the issue, yum installed in Debian, probably as a result of trying to install stackdriver a while ago using yum and probably why that failed initially!

Comment: Great to hear the error message gone after uninstalling yum. It has no use over a Linux OS.

For your other questions I will update my answer.

Comment: @OliverChapple If the answer solves your doubts please upvote and accept the answer.